# How to optimize getting average values of array?

Tags: c++, optimization

There is a function which is returned the average for all elements from beginning to `i + 1`.

```
std::vector<double> f(const std::vector<double> &v)
{
    std::vector<double> ret(v.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        ret[i] = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.begin() + i + 1, 0.0) / (i + 1);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

How can I optimize this function?

Comment: This might be better suited on [codereview.se]

Comment: Optimize for what? Memory? Performance? Code size?

Comment: Just do one pass manually instead of using `std::accumulate`

Comment: @tadman optimize for performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to recalculate the sum from the beginning at each iteration. Just keep a running sum.

```
std::vector<double> f(const std::vector<double> &v)
{
    std::vector<double> ret(v.size());

    double cur = 0.;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        cur += v[i];
        ret[i] = cur / (i + 1);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This is even amenable to working inplace, so if the caller doesn't mind losing the source vector it can avoid the extra allocation.

```
void f_inplace(std::vector<double> &v)
{
    double cur = 0.;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        cur += v[i];
        v[i] = cur / (i + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::partial_sum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum):

```
std::vector<double> f(const std::vector<double> &v)
{
    std::vector<double> ret(v.size());

    std::partial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), ret.begin());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ret.size(); ++i) {
        ret[i] /= i + 1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `ret[i] /= i + 1` is grouped as `ret[i] /= (i + 1)`.

Comment: this does 2 loops over the array when it can be done with just one.

Comment: @bolov That's a micro optimization in my opinion. I don't see the point in optimizing to that level without benchmarks and/or profiling. It could even happen that 2 loops is faster than 1.

Comment: @Justin absolutely it can happen that 2 loops are better than one. But not in this case...

Comment: @bolov My point is that it's not worth optimizing it further unless you have profiles that show this isn't fast enough and benchmarks to prove that you are improving it.